# Defining inner classes in AppEngine Datastore (Objectify)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

In AppEngine I need to have an `entity Diagram` that contains an `id`, `title` and a variable list of elements of `inner class Box`, each one with `id` and `description`.

Please find below the definition. However, at time of defining the EntityProxy List getter and setter: `"The type java.util.List<Box> cannot be used here"`.

**DIAGRAM.java**

```
@Entity
public class Diagram extends DatastoreObject {

    public class Box {
    private String boxId;
    private String description;
    public String get_id() {
        return boxId;
    }
    public void set_id(String boxId) {
        this.boxId = boxId;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Indexed private String diagramId; // Primary key
    @Indexed private String title;
    @Embedded private List<Box> boxes;

    public String get_id() {
        return diagramId;
    }
    public void set_id(String diagramId) {
        this.diagramId = diagramId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void setBoxes(List<Box> boxes) {
        this.boxes = boxes
    }
    public List<Box> getBoxes() {
        return boxes;
    }
}
```

**DIAGRAMPROXY.java**

```
[...]
    List<Box> getBoxes();
    void setBoxes(List<Box> boxes);
[...]
```

Comment: That's not a subclass, that's an inner class.

Comment: Good point! But the problem is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe take it out of the class, making it a separate class, and see if that helps at all?

Comment: Already tried. Same error...

Comment: maybe you need to declare it as an embedded class?

Comment: Still doesn't work (see updated code...). Thanks

Comment: This is GWT/EntityProxy complaining not Objectify.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how to have this running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusing, you have a `Collection<Box>` in the Box class? Doesnt sound right.. Anyways the inner Box class must be market `static` or be moved to a different file. Use the `@Embed` (version 4.0) annotation on the Box class.

Also, assuming `DatastoreObject` is the base of all your entities, you can make `DatastoreObject` as an `@Entity` and all its sub classes as an `@EntitySubClass (index = true)`. Obviously all sub entities would be be saved under the same 'kind' (DatastoreObject) in the datastore.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner class must be `static`. Nonstatic inner classes have an implicit link to an instance of the outer class, which would be really confusing from the perspective of loading and saving entities to the datastore.